# group by in jquery with .map()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array where each element has a name and a subsection.
I now want to group those elements by subsection.
Is there a way to do a group by inside a mapping function.

The data looks like:
* 0: "name: Study subSection: Education" 
1: "name: Classes subSection: Education" 
2: "name: Society subSection: Social”

I want it to appear as

Education
1.Study
2.Classes

Social
1.Society

Here is my code thus far that isn't working. I think it needs a little tweaking to work properly.

```
let myArray = response.map(item => {
          return   'name: ' + item.name + ' subSection: '  + item.subSection;
        }
        );
let grouppedArray1=_.groupBy(myArray, 'subSection'))
```

Comment: any error? what's the value of `response`?

Comment: You want `reduce()`, not `map()`

Comment: You are also using `_.groupBy()` in your question but the question is not tagged with lodash or underscore.

Comment: can i know the array value and the expected output value, so that i can help u well in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) method generates a string array and you are trying to group by `subSection` property but there is no such property for the string.

You can do something simple using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```
// iterate over the element
let res = response.reduce((obj, item) => {
  // define group if not defined(property with subsection name and value as array)
  obj[item.subSection] = obj[item.subSection] || [];

  // push the value to group
  obj[item.subSection].push('name: ' + item.name + ' subSection: '  + item.subSection);

  // return the object 
  return obj;

  // set initial value as empty object for result
}, {});
```

```js
let response = [{
    "name": "Study",
    subSection: "Education"
  }, {
    "name": "Classes",
    subSection: "Education"
  },
  {
    name: "Society",
    subSection: "Social"
  }
];

let res = response.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.subSection] = obj[item.subSection] || [];
  obj[item.subSection].push('name: ' + item.name + ' subSection: ' + item.subSection);
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

**UPDATE :** To show them as buttons( combined ), do something like this:

```js
let response = [{
    "name": "Study",
    subSection: "Education"
  }, {
    "name": "Classes",
    subSection: "Education"
  },
  {
    name: "Society",
    subSection: "Social"
  }
];

let res = response.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.subSection] = obj[item.subSection] || [];
  obj[item.subSection].push(item.name);
  return obj;
}, {});


// get values array and iterate 
Object.keys(res).forEach(function(k) {
  // generate h3 ith subSection value and append
  $('#container').append(
      $('<h3>', {
        text: k,
        class : 'title'
      })
    )
    // generate buttons and append
    .append(res[k].map(v =>
      $('<button>', {
        text: v,
        class : 'btn btn-default'
      })
    ))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Ok thank you so much. It looks like it can work. I would just need to implement it to my existing functionality. As of now I have the item.Name displaying as buttons. How would I put theis code together?  response.map(item => { item.name });       const button = $("<div></div>").addClass("button");

            programs.forEach(program => {
                const bt = button.clone().text(program);
                $(".programs").append(bt);
            });

Comment: Thank you, i'm not sure if i was clear. I need each item.name to appear in its own button. But the buttons should be organized according to their item.subsection. So anything that falls under the education subsection shud display as a button under the education title

Comment: Here is a partial snapshot of what i'm trying to accomplish. Theres a title with the names underneath it appearing as a button.  https://gyazo.com/2ab440e2792fc55dc32cdd39823ff0a9

Comment: For some reason it's iterating over the result many times over and displaying the titles and the buttons many times over instead of the title once and then all the buttons underneath it.

Comment: Actually I found the issue in my case: it was appending the buttons to every single div in my page. Once I added the class of the div that i wanted the buttons to reside in the code worked! Thank you P.C.B!

Comment: @R.P. : ohhh... Ok... Its better to use an id  for the container and then use it for.appending...

Comment: P.C.B you have been extremely helpful! I am still struggling with adding a css class to all buttons and another css class to all titles in the loop. Any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Comment: @R.P. : `$('#container').append(
      $('<h3>', {
        text: k,
        class : 'title'
      })
    )
    // generate buttons and append
    .append(res[k].map(v =>
      $('<button>', {
        text: v,
        class : 'btn btn-default'
      })
    ))`